# Roku: Launching a Premium Application Directly into a Specific Video

Tags: rest, roku

The Roku media player provides a RESTful API with the following commands:

- **query/apps** This ‘query/apps’ returns a map of all the channels installed on the Roku box paired with their app id. This command is accessed via an http GET.
- **keydown** takes an argument describing the key pressed. Keydown is equivalent to pressing down the remote key whose value is the argument passed. This command is sent via a POST with no body.
- **keyup** takes an argument describing the key to release. Keyup is equivalent to releasing the remote key whose value is the argument passed. This command is sent via a POST with no body.
- **keypress** takes an argument describing the key that is pressed. Keyup is equivalent to pressing down and releasing the remote key whose value is the argument passed. This command is sent via a POST with no body.
- **launch** takes an app id as an argument and a list of url parameters that are sent to the app id as an roAssociativeArray passed the the RunUserInterface() or Main() entry point. This command is sent via a POST with no body.

After I get a query a list of applications like so:

```
<apps>
<app id="5127" version="1.0.28">Roku Spotlight</app>
<app id="11" version="2.2.2002">Roku Channel Store</app>
<app id="28" version="2.0.20">Pandora</app>
<app id="12" version="2.4.6">Netflix</app>
<app id="13" version="3.2.7">Amazon Instant Video</app>
<app id="2285" version="2.1.1">Hulu Plus</app>
</apps>
```

I want to launch the Netflix (ID 12) application into a specific TV program or Movie:

```
POST /launch/12?foo=bar&someVar=someValue HTTP/1.1
```

Where foo and someVar are variables that I would send to Netflix that would correspond to that particular piece of content. However, I don't know which variables nor which values I need to send to the premium applications.

Is there any list of params that are accepted by Netflix/Amazon/Hulu/etc?

Comment: Hmm, good question. I wonder if the debug console shows anything meaningful if you launch the URL with an intentionally wrong variable name?

Comment: @Peder Rice What did you end up with? I am looking for a similar solution and I stumbled across your post - so thought I would ask.

Comment: I'm not sure if anything has changed, but at the time of this question, there was no way to launch Hulu or other applications directly into a specific video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently these content providers do not provide an interface for launching content externally. The best you can do is use for example, the Netflix API to add content to the user's Queue. There are several 3rd party Roku channels that do this already, specifically Instant Watch Browser and MultiQ's, both are in the Roku Channel Store.

Comment: So only if an App provides an interface can you launch content externally? What if you know the "filename", could you do it that way? (I'm thinking using wireshark to capture the network traffic to find the file amazon/netflix/etc is streaming)

Answer (score 1):

I recently wrote a small python script which enables me to control my Roku and launch and play tv shows and movies directly within Netflix/Hulu/Amazon/etc.

It makes use of the search functionality of the External Control API, and then follows up with a scripted series of keypresses to blindly play the first search result.

It seems to be working pretty well for me, so far! I have even wired it up to my Amazon Alexa, so I can launch just about anything I want, entirely by voice!

Here's the URL to the github project, if you are interested:

https://github.com/tomchapin/roku-search-launcher